# No resource methods have been found for resource class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature

Tags: rest, maven, jersey

com.sun.jersey</groupId> jersey-bundle</artifactId> 
            1.19.3</version> </dependency> -->
         com.sun.jersey</groupId> jersey-json</artifactId> 
            1.17.1</version> </dependency> -->
         com.sun.jersey</groupId> jersey-core</artifactId> 
            1.19.3</version> </dependency> -->
        
        
            org.glassfish.jersey.core
            jersey-common
            2.26-b03
        
         com.sun.jersey</groupId> jersey-servlet</artifactId> 
            1.19.3</version> </dependency> -->
        
        
            org.jvnet.mimepull
            mimepull
            1.9.7
        
         org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId> 
            1.9.13</version> </dependency> -->
         com.sun.jersey</groupId> jersey-server</artifactId> 
            1.19</version> </dependency> -->
        
        
            org.glassfish.jersey.core
            jersey-server
            2.26-b03
        
        
        
            org.glassfish.jersey.media
            jersey-media-jaxb
            2.26-b03

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId> 
        <version>1.19.3</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.26-b03</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have these dependencies (TomEE + Eclipse ) and when I start the server I got these warning: WARNING: No resource methods have been found for resource class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.
When I try to upload a file I got the exception:

SEVERE: No message body reader has been found for class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, ContentType: multipart/form-data;boundary=Boundary_1_231756373_1495450602910
May 22, 2017 1:56:43 PM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1315)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:826)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:789)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:212)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:245)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1102)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:788)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1485)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why adding glassfish when tomee already provides you these dependencies? I'd just drop them all from the pom and you wouldnt get a conflict between cxf and jersey.